# Using tf.contrib.opt.ScipyOptimizerInterface with tf.keras.layers, loss not changing

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I want to use the external optimizer interface within tensorflow, to use newton optimizers, as tf.train only has first order gradient descent optimizers. At the same time, i want to build my network using tf.keras.layers, as it is way easier than using tf.Variables when building large, complex networks. I will show my issue with the following, simple 1D linear regression example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
import numpy as np

#generate data
no = 100
data_x = np.linspace(0,1,no)
data_y = 2 * data_x + 2 + np.random.uniform(-0.5,0.5,no)
data_y = data_y.reshape(no,1)
data_x = data_x.reshape(no,1)

# Make model using keras layers and train
x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None,1])
y = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None,1])

output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=None)(x)

loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(data_y, output)
optimizer = tf.contrib.opt.ScipyOptimizerInterface(loss, method="L-BFGS-B")

sess = K.get_session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

tf_dict = {x : data_x, y : data_y}
optimizer.minimize(sess, feed_dict = tf_dict, fetches=[loss], loss_callback=lambda x: print("Loss:", x))
```

When running this, the loss just does not change at all. When using any other optimizer from tf.train, it works fine. Also, when using tf.layers.Dense() instead of tf.keras.layers.Dense() it does work using the ScipyOptimizerInterface. So really the question is what is the difference between tf.keras.layers.Dense() and tf.layers.Dense(). I saw that the Variables created by tf.layers.Dense() are of type tf.float32_ref while the Variables created by tf.keras.layers.Dense() are of type tf.float32. As far as I now, _ref indicates that this tensor is mutable. So maybe that's the issue? But then again, any other optimizer from tf.train works fine with keras layers.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of digging I was able to find a possible explanation.

ScipyOptimizerInterface uses feed_dicts to simulate the updates of your variables during the optimization process. It only does an assign operation at the very end. In contrast, tf.train optimizers always do assign operations. The code of ScipyOptimizerInterface is not that complex so you can verify this easily.

Now the problem is that assigining variables with feed_dict is working mostly by accident. Here is a [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/19884#issuecomment-397485615) where I learnt about this. In other words, assigning variables via feed dict, which is what ScipyOptimizerInterface does, is a hacky way of doing updates.

Now this hack mostly works, except when it does not. tf.keras.layers.Dense uses ResourceVariables to model the weights of the model. This is an improved version of simple Variables that has cleaner read/write semantics. The problem is that under the new semantics the feed dict update happens after the loss calculation. The link above gives some explanations.

Now tf.layers is currently a thin wrapper around tf.keras.layer so I am not sure why it would work. Maybe there is some compatibility check somewhere in the code.

The solutions to adress this are somewhat simple.

- Either avoid using components that use ResourceVariables. This can be kind of difficult.
- Patch ScipyOptimizerInterface to do assignments for variables always. This is relatively easy since all the required code is in one file.

There was some effort to make the interface work with eager (that by default uses the ResourceVariables). Check out this [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/24089/commits/0d5958addacadfce98fc3a09e91a516a0bd8aceb)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the line

```
output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=None)(x)
```

In this format *output* is not a layer but rather the output of a layer, which might be preventing the wrapper from collecting the weights and biases of the layer and feed them to the optimizer. Try to write it in two lines e.g.

```
output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=None)
res = output(x)
```

If you want to keep the original format then you might have to manually collect all trainables and feed them to the optimizer via the var_list option

```
optimizer = tf.contrib.opt.ScipyOptimizerInterface(loss, var_list = [Trainables], method="L-BFGS-B")
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this does not change anything.